# Move space from Windows to Linux

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I want to modify my partitions by resizing sda3 (Windows) to create unallocated space and reallocating it to sda9 (Linux). How do I go about this as they are not next to each other?

Here's a screenshot of my partitions:

[image: Screenshot of partitions shown in GParted]

Comment: Is sda9 a / or /home? I might shrink Windows using Windows tools, and do a new install in unallocated space. And then expand sda8 to use sda9's space after data backed up. You may be able to use gparted to move partitions left & expand right. But copy can be slow and any interruption totally corrupts data. Or you must have good backups.

Comment: sda8 is / while sda9 is /home. I was thinking of 
1. Using Disk Management to shrink Windows
2. Then use gparted from a live usb to expand sda8 to include the new unallocated space
3. Use gparted to create unallocated space from sda8 and resize sda9 to include this space again.
Would this be okay and would it corrupt my Linux partitions?

Comment: You have to move left and expand right. Move is the task that can take time depending on system and amount of data. Again if you have a power failure or battery dies or you think it is taking too long and stop it in the middle all you data is corrupted. You must have good backups.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resizing Ubuntu Partition, but the partitions are not adjacent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598141/resizing-ubuntu-partition-but-the-partitions-are-not-adjacent)